# NAN when adding two templates in xslt

Tags: templates, sum, xslt-1.0

I have defined two templates separately. When i call each of them individually i am getting correct value.
But when i add them the value is showing as NAN.

Gross weight total : 33.00 1,261.98 NaN

Can anyone help me on this!

Sample refrence:

```
<xsl:variable name="A1">
      <xsl:call-template name="AWeight">
           <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="cXML/A1/A2/A3/P1[PCode='aux']"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>  

<xsl:variable name="A2">
      <xsl:call-template name="BWeight">
           <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="cXML/B1/B2/B3/"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$A1"/><xsl:value-of select="$A2"/>

<xsl:value-of select="number($A1) + number($A2)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your named templates (which you do not show us!) are programmed to return a **formatted** number, e.g `1,261.98`.

A value that contains a comma thousands separator is not a number and cannot be converted to a number using the `number()` function.

Either tell your templates to return an unformatted number and format it only when writing it to the output, or use the `translate()` function to remove the comma before attempting to use the value in an arithmetic operation.